# How to classify real continuous data for WEKA

Tags: machine-learning, weka

This is my data

```
@attribute Service_type {Fund,Loan,CD,Bank_Account,Mortgage}
@attribute Customer {Student,Business,Other,Doctor,Professional}
@attribute Monthly_fee real
@attribute Advertisement_budget real
@attribute Size {Small,Large,Medium}
@attribute Promotion {Web&Email,Full,Web,None}
@attribute Interest_rate real
@attribute Period real
@attribute Label real
```

And this is one corresponding row.

```
Fund,Student,0.64,0.95,Small,Full,0,10,26.72
```

The problem is that I want to predict the LABEL attribute that is real but weka doenst give me the option for J48 decision tree.

I got this tip that i Need to classify my LABEL attribute into ranges like 
 LABEL is greater than 25 &&  LABEL is less than 30  as C1 and so on.

My question is that is there any other way to do this for J48 or is there any specific way or rationale to atleast classify the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define what you mean by "classify the data", as that's ambiguous in the context of real-valued class labels. If a hypothetical classifier predicted Label=26.7200000000001 for your example row, should that be considered correct? If so, at what epsilon is that no longer true? If not, you're probably screwed by virtue of the inherent nature of how computers deal with real numbers.

J48 doesn't (and can't really) address these issues. It needs a finite number of values to choose from. The conventional way of doing this is, as your tip said, discretize the variable. So instead of having an infinite number of labels, you have one label for "0<=x<10", another for "10<=x<20", etc. How exactly to do that is problem dependent -- how much precision do you need, what is the range of values you can observe, etc. The finer the discretization, the more accurate the resulting classifier can be, but at the expense of time and the amount of training data needed.

If you don't want to discretize the output variable like that, the other approach is to treat it as a regression problem rather than a classification problem. There, the goal is to output a real number such that some measure of error (e.g., mean squared error over the entire training set) is minimized. J48 isn't a good choice for this approach. I don't do a lot with Weka, but it seems the `weka.classifiers.functions` namespace holds the basic Weka support for regression models. Alternately, if you want to stick with something based on decision trees, you might look at `weka.classifiers.trees.M5P`.

Note that this isn't really my area of expertise, but since you hadn't received any other answers in 18 hours or so, I thought this might be of some help. Just bear in mind that if you see something that contradicts me, don't automatically assume I got the details right.